# Why was mapmisc package removed from CRAN? Substitutes?

Tags: r, cran

When I installed the latest version of R studio, I realize that I can not install the package miscmap from CRAN, making a bunch of maps I am creating looking very badly without its support.

I found this message that it has been removed from CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapmisc/index.html

I have these doubts and appreciate help as I can not find answers:

1. Why has it been removed?
2. Is there a substitute in the above page it says nothing
3. Can I get its functionality from another package now?
4. If none of the above... could anyone point me to instructions to install a package from an archive I have not been very successful in finding how

I found this but refers to github not the CRAN archive: [Installing a Package Removed from CRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67978168/installing-a-package-removed-from-cran)

And this is similar too but has no answer:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The package has been archived because the CRAN build found errors which the maintainer did not correct. The errors appear to be related to the impending [r-spatial evolution](https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html).  As for whether there is a substitute, it is very likely that the functionality you are looking for exists somewhere else, but _you have not told us what functionality you need_. Please post a specific example indicating what it is you are trying to do, so that we can show how it may be done using alternate methods.