# Why am I unable to build data frame with census block and lat/long outline?

Tags: r, leaflet, tigris, tidycensus

I am new to R and working with census data and I am trying to build a csv file that can be passed to another team that shows the lat/long outline of census blocks.

With this I can get to 3 specific census blocks in Florida.

```
FL_blocks <- blocks("FL", year = 2010, )
FL_blocks_Alachua <- filter(FL_blocks, COUNTYFP == "001")
NTIA_FL_CB <- FL_blocks_Alachua %>%
  filter(FL_blocks_Alachua$GEOID10 %in% c ("120010019071008", "120010019071007", "120010019071009"))
```

Now I would like to make a table that just shows the lat/long and the corresponding census block that lat/long is associated with. This will give me the list of the lat/long for each census block and I can plot them with the polygon of the census block, but for me to pass this to a team unfamiliar with R, I need the csv data output.

```
NTIA_FL_CB_Shape_xy <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(NTIA_FL_CB$geometry))
NTIA_FL_CB_Shape_xy <- NTIA_FL_CB_Shape_xy %>%
    rename( Longitude = X, Latitude = Y) %>%
    select(Latitude,Longitude )

# save lat/long as csv
st_write(NTIA_FL_CB_Shape_xy, "fl_3cb_ntia_latlong.csv", coords = TRUE)

# plot the 3 census blocks with the outline of the shapefiles marked as green circles
leaflet(NTIA_FL_CB) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(popup = ~GEOID10) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = NTIA_FL_CB_Shape_xy, color = "green")
```

[This image shows what I was thinking, If I could pass the lat/longs outlining each census block the team that uses my csv file output should be able to load that into their GIS software to overlay.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP2zo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to cast to point, then export. Or, if your team is using GIS software, you could write your multipolygon to a shapefile?

```
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc_pt <- st_cast(nc, "POINT")
st_write(nc_pt, "nc_pt.csv", layer_options="GEOMETRY=AS_XY")
# st_write(nc, "nc.shp")
```

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294921/convert-shapefile-into-lat-long-points-and-export-it-as-csv-in-r

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Do you have any tricks on getting this csv or even in st_write for prepping a kml or kmz file?

Comment: Glad to help. Here's how you could do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813141/how-to-create-a-kml-file-using-r. Good luck!